# What does void mean, or how does it affect T in this case?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

So I was doing some work with a friend of mine in C++, and we came across this in the documentation.

```cpp
//(until C++14)
template<class T>
struct less;
```

```cpp
//(since C++14)
template<class T = void>
struct less;
```

Now I know how it works with `class T = int` and the same for double and float and other types of classes. But the part I am very confused about, is how does void act in this case? And what are the limitations by using void?

I'm asking this because the C++ documentation is very helpful nor can I find anywhere else that explains it.

Comment: It works the same way as `class T = int`,  except `T` will be `void` instead of `int`.

Comment: This might also help: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given your code snippet I am going to assume you are referring the function object from the standard library, that is, [std::less](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less).

In general, the declaration `template<class T = void>` works exactly as for other types (such as `int`, for example).
In short, when an object of that class is instantiated without specifying the type template argument, then `void` will be deducted.

```
std::less<int> li;   // std::less<T = int>;
std::less<void> lv;  // std::less<T = void>;
std::less<> lv2;     // std::less<T = void>; exactly as one row above.
```

In this particular case, `std::less` provides a *template specialization* when `T = void`.

The object [`std::less<void>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less_void) is a handy specialization which allows deducing the types to compare "automatically" with the `operator()`. Moreover, it needed when you want to compare two different types which are not implicitly convertible.

---

**Practical Example:**

Let us assume you have two objects you can compare.

```
/*Let us assume you have two objects you can compare*/
struct Foo;
struct Bar;

struct Foo {
  bool operator<(const Bar&) const;  
};

struct Bar {
  bool operator<(const Foo&) const;
};
```

`Foo` and `Bar` can be compared to each other, but they are different types.

Which template type will you specify for the functor `std::less` in this case?

```
void WrongCode() {
  std::less<Foo> l;
  l(Foo{}, Bar{});  // error
}
```

If we use `std::less<Foo>` then the functor will only accept objects of type `Foo`. (Of course, the same is for `std::less<Bar>`).

Therefore, the standard provides this handy specialization to cover this case.

```
void GoodCode() {
  std::less<> l;
  l(Foo{}, Bar{});  // this compile
}
```

`GoodCode` will compile because the types of `operator()` of `std::less<void>` are automatically deducted (and they can even be different).

Comment: This answer explained it more for me. I'll update this one to the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 14):

**`void` is a type.**

There are some restrictions on how the `void` type may be used, but nevertheless, `void` is a valid type in the type system. Therefore, it is allowed to have `void` as an argument for a template parameter, including as a default argument.

So, if you type `std::less<>` then it means `std::less<void>`.

The question of what `std::less<void>` *means* is a separate one: normally, `std::less<T>` compares `T` values, but there are no values of type `void`. Instead, `std::less<void>` is a special case: you can pass two values of any (possibly different) types to it, as long as they can be compared. See [the cppreference.com article on `std::less<void>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less_void).

Comment: Thanks, that was the type of answer I was looking for, has helped me and my friend understand heaps better.

Answer (score 3):

In general it just means that you are going to specialize a class for the type void to process a special case.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T = void>
struct A
{
    void operator ()( const T & t ) const 
    { 
        std::cout << "primary template\n"; 
        std::cout << 2 * t << '\n';
    }
};

template <>
struct A<>
{
    template <typename U>
    void operator ()( const U &u ) const 
    { 
        std::cout << "specialization for void\n";
        std::cout << 10 * u << '\n';
    }
};

int main()
{
    A<int>()( 1 );
    A<>()( 1 );
}
```

Its output is

```
primary template
2
specialization for void
10
```

Comment: It may not even be a "special case"